# Generate Lombok annotations with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, lombok, gradle-plugin, byte-buddy

My goal is to add some Lombok annotations (e.g. `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@NoArgsConstructor`, etc.) into a class during a Gradle build, such that the annotations are recognized by the Lombok annotation processor and cause it to generate code for the respective annotations.

Using ByteBuddy and the [ByteBuddy Gradle plugin](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/tree/master/byte-buddy-gradle-plugin) works well to add annotations with `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`; but adding Lombok annotations via the same mechanism does not result in generated code, presumably because the Gradle `byteBuddy` task runs after the `compileJava` task and so Lombok has already finished its code generation by the time ByteBuddy adds annotations.

Is there a way to make ByteBuddy run before Lombok in the Gradle build cycle? Is ByteBuddy the wrong tool for this job? Is there another way to insert Lombok annotations into source files during the build?

Comment: It's the wrong tool. ByteBuddy and the corresponding gradle plugin use the compiled byte code to do modifications, whereas lombok needs the AST, which only exists during compilation.
I don't know a solution. It's probably complicated. Lombok doesn't interact with other annotation processors very well, so using an AP could be problematic, either.

Comment: As @JanRieke says, you would need a source code transformation tool of which there are few. Byte Buddy operates on the byte code level and cannot add annotations that are visible to source code transformers unless you'd decompile the transformed byte code what sounds like the wrong approach to me.